# REST collections: pagination enabled by default?

Tags: rest, pagination

I am trying to figure out what is the common way to respond on GET operation to retrieve multiple resources. For example, if user calls: `/books` or `/books?name=*foo*` etc what should good REST api return?

[A] list of *all* resources in collection. Only if user specifies a range (using `start` and `limit` or in any other way), then only a page of results is returned.

[B] *always* return a first page of resources, even when nothing is specified. Then user may continue with pagination, using the parameters (or any other way).

[C] a document indicating that paging is be involved, with total number of resources in the collection, but without any returned resource; with appropriate status code set (like `300` if I remember correctly at this moment). This response indicates to the user that he can start fetching its data using pagination parameters.

I like C approach, but could not find APIs that are having this.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on either the pagination parameters are mandatory or not. For most APIs it's mandatory simply because `/books` could return millions of entries.

How about [D]: [a redirect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302).

If the client accesses `/books` or `/books?name=foobar` redirect it to `/books?page=1&size=15` or `/books?name=foobar&page=1&size=15` and return results according to those default parameters.

You could also include [pagination links](http://restcookbook.com/Resources/pagination/) into your response (as per [HATEOAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HATEOAS)) with a `rel` attribute that specifies that a link is for the next page, previous, first or last page, so the client can also navigate back and forth between the result pages.

Comment: thanks a lot, it looks like the most sane think to do